# Restructuring data in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

My results currently return the following:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | item1 | item2 | item3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
|  2 |     0 |     1 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

I would like them to be:

```
+-----------+
| ID | item |
+-----------+
| 1 | item1 |
| 1 | item3 |
| 2 | item2 |
| 2 | item3 |
| 3 | item1 |
| 3 | item2 |
| 3 | item3 |
+-----------+
```

Is restructuring the data like this possible?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the query you are using so we can tell what you've already tried.

Comment: is column are static i.e only Item 3 or they can grow ?

Comment: **(1)** How does the original data looks like? it might be easier to skip the intermediate result set **(2)** What is the next step? what are you going to do with the query results? **(3)** What type are the item columns? what values can they have? only 0/1?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `union all` to create the results:

```
with t as (
      <yourqueryhere>
     )
select id, 'item1' as item from t where item1 > 0 union all
select id, 'item2' as item from t where item2 > 0 union all
select id, 'item3' as item from t where item3 > 0;
```

There might be another, simpler, solution based on modifications to your query.  Without knowing what the query is, though, it is not possible to say.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use the *unpivoting* trick using a `cross join` and `case` like this:

```
select
    id, item
from (
    select
        t.id,
        case
            when x.i = 1 and item1 = 1 then 'item1'
            when x.i = 2 and item2 = 1 then 'item2'
            when x.i = 3 and item3 = 1 then 'item3'
        end as item
    from your_table t
    cross join (
        select 1 i union all
        select 2 i union all
        select 3 i
    ) x
) t where item is not null;
```

Note: this method reads the table once.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      id,item

from        td_unpivot
            (
                on      ({put your query here})

                using   value_columns   ('val')
                        unpivot_column  ('item')
                        column_list     ('item1','item2','item3')
            ) u

where       val = 1

order by    id,item
```

---

```
+----+-------+
| ID | item  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | item1 |
|  1 | item3 |
|  2 | item2 |
|  2 | item3 |
|  3 | item1 |
|  3 | item2 |
|  3 | item3 |
+----+-------+
```